# My Dye Trader Didn't Spawn

Tags: terraria

I recently acquired a teal mushroom, and I got a message saying the dye trader arrived. However, he isn't there. When I click on the house icon that shows which NPC lives in which house, his banner isn't there, and I assume he didn't spawn since I haven't seen him. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPC's don't spawn if there isn't anywhere for them to live. You may have any other structures away from where you're looking for him, that he might be living in.

The best way to make sure he is spawned, is to check for his portrait in the NPC menu on the right side of the screen. If you see him there you can set his house to whichever one you want him living in, and he should then move accordingly.